# What's the correct markup for a message informing about unavailable content?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, wai-aria

```
<article>
    <h1>MyProductName V22290</h1>
    <p>The description for this product is currently unavailable</p>
    <a href="buy/229283">Buy</a>
</article>
```

The `<p>` element is not a really the description of the product, but rather an error message that informs about the absence of the description.

How should the markup for that text look like? Maybe *html-aria* can help?

Comment: There's no specific markup for error messages. After all, it's just a paragraph of text. You can make screen readers ignore them with aria-hidden if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The message "*The description for this product is currently unavailable*" is an important information that screenreader should read as it informs their users that no description is available.

Without that information, users may need to listen to the whole page trying to find the description of the product.

Also do not forget that there are a lot of people with low vision using both a screen magnifier and a screenreader for assistance, and that any visible text should be made readable by a screenreader.

EDIT: As indicated in the comments bellow, you still can use an `<em>` tag to indicate stress emphasis

Comment: The question is asking if there is any way to indicate in the markup itself that the <p> element does not represent an actual description. To that end, I would add that the message is self-explanatory and that there is neither a dedicated feature for this, nor a need for such a feature.

Comment: Exactly. I would put it this way: An ARIA attribute should be considered a "fix" for a problem that no more appropriate solution could be found for. But _The description for this product is currently unavailable_ conveys the information that, well, the description for this product is currently unavailable, perfectly already. This doesn't need any more than the ability to be read in the standard way - by the human eye, or any assistive technology - to do its job. On the contrary, throw the "wrong" ARIA attribute or whatever additional technology at it, and you could be making things worse.

Comment: If anything, I could see a `<p><em>...</em></p>` construct making some sense here maybe. This could help convey the information that what is usually found/expected in this position is not available two ways, visually (apply sensible formatting at own discretion - italics, maybe go a little lower on text color contrast) and when read by a screen reader.